# ADB server not starting in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb

I have installed Unity 2019.4 with the Android SDK/NDK. An ADB server cannot start with this error:

```
UnityEditor.Android.Command.RunWithShellExecute (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg) (at <303ae0e7a8d8441ab049e592bd1e2100>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.StartServer () (at <303ae0e7a8d8441ab049e592bd1e2100>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <303ae0e7a8d8441ab049e592bd1e2100>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.GetKnownTargets (UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler) (at <303ae0e7a8d8441ab049e592bd1e2100>:0)
UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.GetKnownTargets () (at <7d90b28560b644ce87b8263efcc36eed>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildWindowExtension+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<SpawnFetchTargetsThread>b__0 () (at <303ae0e7a8d8441ab049e592bd1e2100>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart()
```

I tried running adb in the terminal but it could not start either. I have already made bypasses through in the windows firewall. It had this output:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
adb.exe: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon
```

I am using windows for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have something else like Oculus Developer Hub installed, that may be conflicting with the Unity install.

What you need to do is copy `adb.exe`, `AdbWinApi.dll`, and `AdbWinUsbApi.dll` from the Unity
`Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools` folder to wherever they are located in the conflicting program - in the case of Oculus Developer Hub:
`C:/Program Files/Oculus Developer Hub/resources/bin`. Then, restart your computer to apply changes. Please note you may need to kill these processes in order to run them.

If this does not work, install the vanilla Android SDK, and copy the same files from the SDK/platform-tools folder to the location of the conflicting program. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution that worked for me was.. closing other softwares that use other versions of ADB. In my case, it was Android studio that was running another version of ADB.

Comment: A similar case: I had VS Code open with a Flutter project with Android build support. Closing it fixed my Unity issue.